# formatting decimal value in column in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, formatting

I want to formatting a column of sum value: for example I have 19240 I want it 192.40 I tried many way but nothing

```
dgw.Grid.Columns["Sum"].DefaultCellStyle.Format="0:00" // 192:40

dgw.Grid.Columns["Sum"].DefaultCellStyle.Format="n"    // 19240.00

dgw.Grid.Columns["Sum"].DefaultCellStyle.Format="0.00" // 19240.00

dgw.Grid.Columns["Sum"].DefaultCellStyle.Format=string.Format("{0:0.##}") // Exception
```

I want all items in that column in datagrid view with the same format

**edit** :  *a way to do it*:

I use this methode to get what I want

```
    int _sum;
    public int Sum
    {
        get { return _sum; }
        set { _sum= value; }
    }

    public double SumAsdouble
    {
        get
        {
            if (_sum== 0)
                return 0;
            else
                return Convert.ToDouble(_sum) / 100;

        }
    }
```

and I make hidden the Sum and show the SumAsdouble

and this work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the value in the cell?

It looks like it is 19240, which means that formatting it to 2DP will return 19240.00, as you are seeing. If you want 192.40, then you'll need to divide by 100 first - you'll not be able to do this with string formats.

Comment: the value is int; then the only way is to change it to decimal and divide it by 100 then I set the items in datagrid ?

Comment: @Akrem - to be honest, that would be the clearest way to do it as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you always want to have the last two digits to be decimal digits and that your number is always five digits long. Then you can use "000.00" or "%" as format string. Alternatively, you can devide your number by 100.